# cant import tf_sentencepiece - Reason: image not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to import the library tf_sentencepiece for the purpose of using the following [link](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/1). Using macOS  , already installed the library via pip and got :

```
pip install tf_sentencepiece
Requirement already satisfied: tf_sentencepiece in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.1.82)
```

When importing the library i get the error message :

```
NotFoundError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_sentencepiece/_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so.1.13.1, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libtensorflow_framework.so
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_sentencepiece/_sentencepiece_processor_ops.so.1.13.1
  Reason: image not found.
```

I also receive the warning alert :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_sentencepiece/sentencepiece_processor_ops.py:38: UserWarning: No so file is found for [1.14.0] from [1.12.0, 1.11.0, 1.8.0, 1.7.0, 1.10.0, 1.9.0, 1.13.1]
  ', '.join(versions)))
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tf_sentencepiece/sentencepiece_processor_ops.py:39: UserWarning: use the latest version 1.13.1
  warnings.warn('use the latest version %s' % (latest))
```

Any idea about what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading tensorflow to version 1.13.1 fix the issue. As the library  tf_sentencepiece support tensorflow up to version 1.13.1 .